# redirecting a wordpress site to subdirectory using .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a Wordpress site installed in a directory /newsite and I'm trying to have it accessible from the root directory - www.outcrossrecords.com

I've copied the index.php & .htaccess files to the root and changed the URL in the general settings within Wordpress, but it still isn't working.

I read that you need to update the .htaccess file and ive added the following to it exactly as it it below...

```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?outcrossrecords.com$ [NC]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^newsite/
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /newsite/$1
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?outcrossrecords.com$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(/)?$newsite/index.php [L]
```

is there something I'm missing out or have done wrong that's preventing this from working?

The .htaccess file previously was this...

```
 # Switch rewrite engine off in case this was installed under HostPay.
 RewriteEngine Off

 AddHandler application/x-httpd-php53 .php .php5

 DirectoryIndex index.cgi index.php

 # BEGIN WordPress

 # END WordPress
```

Comment: The last line should be `RewriteRule ^/?$ newsite/index.php [L]`. (with one space before newsite). What exactly is the problem ?

Comment: The page isn't being displayed, I'm only getting a white screen

Comment: Still the same - www.outcrossrecords.com

Comment: Is .htaccess the only option?! Or could you set the DocumentRoot for the web server?

Comment: Nothing seems to be working

Comment: A white screen can be an indication of WordPress mis-configuration. If you look in the wp_options table in the WordPress database for an option called "siteurl", does it contain "http://your.site.name/newsite/wp"?